# Build a Search Query in zend Framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

i am using ZendFrameWork 1.11.5
i need to make a Multi form search queries like i have 5 fields like

```
name (text box)
city (dropDown)
zipCode (text box)
type (dropdown)
```

now the problem is ...
in text Box user can enter anything it could be correct info or not..
kindly suggest me how to build a fast query.what kind of options i have.. 
also i tried this but not working.. not giving me correct result..

```
Select * from table where type =       '%$pType%'
                OR  sex     LIKE     '%$sex%'
                OR  race    LIKE      '%$race%'
                OR  kind    LIKE     '%$kind%'
                OR  country LIKE      '%$Country%'
                OR  state   LIKE     '%$statesIDs%'
                OR  zipcode LIKE     '%$zip%'";
```

Comment: You are on the right track but in the query you use variables which are not defined (you don't have $race defined, only $name, $city, $zipcode and $type). So, take out all the non-existent variable names and use for example race LIKE '%$name%' so they can search for anything in the name box.

Comment: @LéonRodenburg actually.. i just give you an example of my code.. eveything is defined..
i just need to asure..what i am doing is correct.. but if correct why not its giving me the correct result..
like entry contains in database is female ...if i select Male.. then it also displays me the Make entries..

Comment: That's because you are using OR, so every record that fulfills one of these conditions will be shown. If you search for name = 'a' and male, then it will show Adam, a male, and Ada, a female, because they both fulfill the name condition.

Comment: @LéonRodenburg then i guess i should use 'And'.. let me try this..

Comment: @LéonRodenburg We are not even sure what 'Correct Result' means in your case. For all you know, 'OR' could be your right logic or 'AND' or even a mixture of both. You know what you expect from the search. Your variables also could be an issue, for instance the values of your drop-downs might be ID's and not the string you expect it is....

Comment: I'm not the OP... I just pointed out the way OR works in a query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my sample code for you. Your code should depends on your needs, query may joins with another table, or instead of `LIKE` you can use `MATCH...AGAINST` for more accuracy result. This code depends on each parameter that user enter for making a final query.

```
//In DbTable
public function search($params)
{
    $query = $this->select()
                   ->from(
                    array('tbl'=>'table'),
                    array('name','city','zipcode','type')
                    );
    $query = $this->_makeParams($query,$params);
    return $this->fetchAll($query);
}

private function _makeParams($query, $params)
{
    $name = isset($params['name']) ? trim($params['name']) : '';
    $city = isset($params['city']) ? trim($params['city']) : '';
    $zipcode = isset($params['zipcode']) ? trim($params['zipcode']) : '';
    $type = isset($params['type']) ? trim($params['type']) : '';

    if($name!='')
    {
        $name = '%'.$this->quote($name).'%';//quote is my own function
        $query->where("tbl.name LIKE '?'",$name); 
    }

    if($city!='')
    {
        $query->where("tbl.city=?",$city);
    }

    if($zipcode!='')
    {
        $query->where("tbl.zipcode=?",$zipcode);
    }

    if($type!='')
    {
        $query->where("tbl.type=?",$type);
    }

    return $query;

}
```